# Which languages are required to learn animation designing?

Tags: animation

I want to design animations, short animated video clips but even after Googling a little I got no clue about it.

I want ways that include programming rather than mouse clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what software you are going to use, in Adobe Flash it's called ActionScript, Autodesk 3Ds Max has something called MaxScript and Unity 3D's language is called UnityScript.

```
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript.html
http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/
```

Comment: Can you suggest which one will suit me?
I like C,Java,PHP,Python type languages.  (hope you got my taste)

Comment: Thanks. Got it! 
Animations are just a part of any language :)